# Difference "he didn't be a doctor" and "he wasn't a doctor"?

Tags: auxiliary-verbs, do-support

What the difference between "he didn't be a doctor" and "he wasn't a doctor"?

Comment: Although 'He wanted to be a doctor' ('His desire was to become a doctor'), 'He intended to be a doctor',  'He was going to be a doctor' ... are all acceptable, 'He didn't be a doctor' isn't. 'He didn't become a doctor' does work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the grammatical sentence

- *He wasn't a doctor*

the first auxiliary verb (*was*) is contracted with *not* to form *wasn't*.
That's the way the rule goes: *Not* may contract with the first auxiliary verb in a [verb phrase](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/VPguide.pdf).

In the ungrammatical sentence (the asterisk in front of it marks it as ungrammatical)

- **He didn't be a doctor*

The negative is not contracted with the first auxiliary verb, but rather *be* is treated as a main verb and *Do*-Support is invoked to insert the past tense of *do* as the first auxiliary verb, which is then contracted with *not* to produce *didn't be*. This is ungrammatical because *be* is **always** an auxiliary verb, and [does not allow *Do*-Support](https://english.stackexchange.com/a/78591/15299) (except in imperatives with Action *do*, like *Do be quiet*).

Comment: I suppose [*Be quiet, they shout. So they **did** be quiet*](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22so+they+did+be+quiet%22) is a kind of "mention" rather than "use". The main difference I see between that and *...they **were** quiet* is that you could reasonably say that second version without particularly stressing ***were***, but the first one only seems to work for me if ***did*** is heavily stressed.

Comment: Just a note to mention that, interestingly, BE might be considered a lexical verb in a few very specific environments, for example negative questions "Why don't you be more careful?" and conditional adjuncts "If you don't be more careful ..." In both of these types of clause we see DO support with BE.

Comment: Only optionally, however, and in -- as you say -- very specific environments. More normal would be _If you aren't more carefu, ...l_ and _Why aren't you more careful?_. Both will be understood as inchoative (becoming more careful), and the version with _do_-support is marked as odd.

Answer (score 0):

> *"he didn't be a doctor"

is grammatically incorrect. I'm not sure what you're trying to express with this. Are you trying to say

> "He didn't become a doctor"

Your other sentence,

> "he wasn't a doctor"

is grammatically correct.

Comment: I think "He didn't become a doctor" more appropriate solution than "He didn't be a doctor". The second variant is grammatically incorrect. Please, edit my comment if I make grammatical mistakes. :)